# Visualization of satellite image - directly in Python

Tags: python, visualisation, imagery

Is there any way (a package or what not), to visualize a GeoTIFF image directly in Python?

I don't want to use ENVI or ArcGIS or anything else.

Comment: What do you mean by 'visualize'? Do you want to see the image in the context of a coordinate system, or just view the image itself?

Comment: Just the image itself. Althought a coordinate system would be nice, I'm not sure about what you mean with this but you made me think RGB coordinates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [PIL](http://www.pythonware.com/products/pil/) and [Tkinter](http://wiki.python.org/moin/TkInter) or other GUI framework to create a simple image viewer. If PIL is unable to read the image you could use [GDAL](http://www.gdal.org/) to convert it to a suitable format before displaying it.

Here's a Tkinter example: http://codeidol.com/python/python3/A-Tkinter-Tour,-Part-1/Viewing-and-Processing-Images-with-PIL/

Comment: I want to visualize REALLY simple images, made by myself, like a 500 x 500 constant matrix with salt and pepper noise. Should be pretty straight forward right? It must be a geotiff file though. ... Dammit, now I'm not sure, anyway, I'll look into what you propose, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 6):

if you are interested with RS - Remote Sensing, you can check out Orfeo Toolbox [here](http://orfeo-toolbox.org/otb/). following information from their site:

> a set of algorithmic components, adapted to large remote sensing
>   images,  which allow to capitalize the methodological know how, and
>   therefore use an incremental approach to benefit from the results of
>   the methodological research.

[image: orfeo]

i hope it helps you...

Comment: +1 This is excellent!  Have you ever used Orfeo for tree cover classification?

Comment: this is an opensource project...  i have only checked out his capability for image processing. i have usually been using envi for now to my licence expire for enterprise works and it is really very good when u work with multi-spectral images.

Answer (score 5):

you can use also Matplotlib with the cartographic module ([Basemap](http://matplotlib.github.com/basemap/)) without problem, see, for example, [Retrieving last images from MODIS Satellites and ploting earthquakes](http://pyevolve.sourceforge.net/wordpress/?p=1013) or [Python: visualiser en temps quasi réel les images satellites et les shapefiles MODIS ou les données sismiques de l'USGS](http://www.portailsig.org/content/python-visualiser-en-temps-quasi-reel-les-images-satellites-et-les-shapefiles-modis-ou-les-d) (in french)

Answer (score 3):

[PIL](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm) (with a limited set of tiff file types) or [ImageMagick](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1740158/documents-and-examples-of-pythonmagick) would to the trick.

Answer (score 3):

Nothing beats GDAL

```
from osgeo import gdal
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
ds = gdal.Open('file.tif').ReadAsArray()

im = plt.imshow(ds)
plt.colorbar(im)
```

And to do some proper mapping with projections included use `cartopy`

Answer (score 3):

[Rasterio](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/) and [matplotlib](http://matplotlib.org/) has all the functionality you need to display and manipulate multiband raster data. For example, here is how you can plot a RBG image using Rasterio:

```
import rasterio
from rasterio.plot import show

indata = '/path/to/your/imagery.tif'

# Note that example uses 4 band NAIP imagery
with rasterio.open(indata) as src:
    arr = src.read([1,2,3], masked=True)
    show(arr)
```

---

[image]